# Reducing plotting area in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just making my first attempts with ggplot... my question may be so basic but I don't find the answer anywhere

I have an object correctly plotted in ggplot

```
a=ggplot(data,aes(x,y))
b=a+geom_line(color="blue",size=2)
```

I would like to reduce the plotting area to have more space for putting bigger axis text and labels so I try with plot.margin:

```
b=a+geom_line(color="blue",size=2)+theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

And I get the message "Error... could not find the function "unit". Iam searching for a clue in google but I find nothing. Please, could you help me? Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Function unit is in library grid. You have to add it before plotting data with library(grid)

Comment: Oh god. Thank you and sorry, it's clearly a duplicate question.